# 3D calculation range from circle

Tags: algorithms, vectors, 3d

Say you have a 3d coordinate system (x,z,y) now inside this you have a Cylinder and an actor who stands on a position (x,y,z)

The following drawing (kinda) illustrates this:

[image]

As shown in the picture what I wish to calculate is the range from the actor (x,y,z) to the closest outline of the Cylinder (note outline, NOT THE CENTER).

I also want to know if the actor is inside or outside of the Cylinder .

Does anyone know how I might do this?

Comment: With a circle in 3D, things are a bit iffy. Do you perhaps mean a sphere or a cylinder?

Comment: @Arthur You are right. it is actually a cylinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance to the cylindre is the distance to the axis (circle center) from which you deduct the radius. If negative, the actor is inside.

As you are dealing with a cylindre, you need to ignore one of the coordinates (I can't tell you which as that depends on your axis convention).

Comment: would it be different if i used a sphere?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen No, you just need to use the center instead of the axis.

Comment: You can't ignore one of the coordinates unless the axis is parallel to one of the coordinate axes.